# How to find website with specific webfont

Tags: fonts, font-face

I have a few specific (web)fonts I want to see in real use, not just in tryouts on fonts.com and similar font shops.

Is there any tool which is able to find me a website where the font XXX is used?

Example: I want to see how looks the real website using eg. Helvetica Neue or another paid font. I put the font name into this tool and will see websites using it. Look how it looks in real use and if it will be okay, I will go to the fonts.com and buy a licence which I need.

Thanks.
RM

Comment: That would be much work for your poor little tool... It would have to visit many many sites and check if the specified font is used there... But in general it's possible

Comment: @MischaBehrend: OK, I understand (I though if exists any "gallery" of webs like CSS Galleries in past years where each web has specified used fonts). If I should be more specific, looking for a web using Masala font now (and others in future).